# Sending empty request using XMLHttpRequest every 5 sec in JS return 304 in Internet Explorer 9

Tags: java, javascript, html, internet-explorer-9, xmlhttprequest

I am writing a web app in java. In my html file I have a small javascript that sends an empty request to the server to preserve the session (HeartBeat) every five seconds.

I am using a `XMLHttpRequest` Object to send the request to a `Tomcat` server.

The problem is that in `IE9`, for the first request I get status `200` and after this, for every request I get `304` answer. In Firefox and Chrome it's working fine.

How can I keep sending empty requests from my Javascript in IE and not getting 304.

My code is:

```
<script>
var HeartBeatTimer; 
function StartHeartBeat(){
   // pulse every 30 seconds
    if (HeartBeatTimer == null)
      HeartBeatTimer = setInterval("HeartBeat()", 1000 * 5);
}

function HeartBeat(){
            var HTTP_Response = new XMLHttpRequest();
    HTTP_Response.open("GET", myurl , true);
    HTTP_Response.send(null);    
}
```

```
my servlet that get the request:

protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
```

}

The purpose of this script is to keep my session alive

Comment: Add a timestamp or an incrementing counter to the url (which is ignored by the server).  IE isn't requesting the page again, because the URL is the same each time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either add a random part to the url or send a `POST` request

```
myurl = myurl + "?_=" + (+new Date());
```

or

```
HTTP_Response.open("POST", myurl, true);
```

For the `POST`-version you will also need to adjust the servlet code.

And don't use a string as the first parameter of `setInterval` or `setTimeout`. Just pass the function itself.

```
setInterval(HeartBeat, 1000 * 5);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the following:

```
HTTP_Response.open("GET", myurl + "&rand=" + Date.now(), true)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can forbid caching by sending following HTTP headers:

```
response.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
response.setDateHeader("Expires", 1L);
response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
response.addHeader("Cache-Control", "no-store");
```